# Inserting elements into array in ksh

Tags: arrays, scripting, ksh

I am trying to insert dynamic elements to Any array after reading from a file. I am using ksh & i am getting error.

cat /user/may/onlySysVols

```
DATA4
DATA5
OSS90
SYSTEM
AUDIT
DATA1
DATA2
DATA3
```

cat tst.sh

```
 1. i=0
 2. grep -Ev "OSS|SYSTEM|AUDIT|VD|LAKE|$escvol" /user/may/onlySysVols |\
 3.   while read lin
 4.   do
 5.     eval ${sysVolArray}'[$i]'="\$lin"
 6.     ((i+=1))
 7.   done
 8.
 9.   echo "${sysVolArray[*]}"
```

Output:

```
./tst.sh[5]: [0]=$DATA1:  not found
./tst.sh[5]: [1]=$DATA2:  not found
./tst.sh[5]: [2]=$DATA3:  not found
./tst.sh[5]: [3]=$DATA4:  not found
./tst.sh[5]: [4]=$DATA5:  not found
```

Desired O/P(Printing an array)

```
DATA1 DATA2 DATA3 DATA4 DATA5
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it : Its in Line 5
It should be 
eval sysVolArray[$i]="\$lin" (no ${sysVolArray})

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a lot simpler

```
sysVolArray=( $(grep -Ev "OSS|SYSTEM|AUDIT|VD|LAKE|$escvol" /usr/may/onlySysVols) )
```